# Replace the Backbone of yolov8 (CSPDarknet53) to Eficientnet in details instruction

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolov8

first of all I'm beginner in computer vision so be bear with me.
I'm trying to replace the backbone of the yolov8 method from the CSPDarknet53 (default backbone) to the Eficientnet and I searched for explanation in details steps, but I only found the general instruction.by change the model.yaml and the cfg files and task.py and so on, but it didn't work so I need video or articles give steps in details to be able to change it.

I modified the .yaml file, modules.py and tasks.py